# How to avoid modifying multiple Visual Studio project files?

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

**The current situation:**
We are developing C Code that will run on an microcontroller. I will call this code the MODEL. It is just a part of the final software which will run on the controller. There are different variants of the software so we have different model code, that is basically the same with commonly used files, but there are also model specific files.
To simulate the behaviour of the model, a FRAMEWORK has been developed. This framework embeds the model code, it provides means for input and output to the model and some evaluation capabilities. The framework is written in C/C++.
In addition to the framework code, the model code is stored in different folders Model_X, Model_Y, ... 
Right now, to run the simulation, you compile the framework together with the model code. We use Visual Studio and have one solution file for each Framework+Model, so there exists Model_X.sln, Model_X.vcxproj, Model_Y.sln, Model_Y.vcxproj, that uses the the same framework code but the different model code.

**The problem:**
Whenever I make changes to the framework (e.g. adding new files to the project), I have to modify every single .vcxproj. It is really a ton of work and also error prone and redundant.

**The question**:
How can I arrange my projects such that I do not need to modify every single .vcxproj file, when making changes to the framework?

**Solution propositions:**

1. Use a script that inserts the include/compile definitions into all
   .vcxproj files

   +: "Quick" solution

   -: It does not really solve the problem
2. Split up each project in two projects, one for the model (Model_X.vcxproj), one for the framework (framework.vcxproj), combine these in one model specific solution (Model_X.sln).

   +: Make framework changes only to framework.vcxproj, which is shared between the .sln files.

   -: If there is a new commonly used file for the model code, we still need to modify all model .vcxproj files.
3. Use a tool like Cmake to generate the .vcxproj files.

   +: Make changes only in one place

   -: The developers will have to make changes to the cmake script and not to the project files

Can you tell me, which ideas make sense in my case and which don't? Do you have any other ideas?